# Find the row name with the highest sum of numbers

Tags: google-sheets, sum, max, google-sheets-formula

In the below spreadsheet, I am trying to find the item with the highest total sales across various hours.

I would like to easily extract the highest and lowest selling item names as well as their corresponding total sales.  I need to be able to do this without creating a helper column as I cannot edit the table.

I know there's probably an easy way to do this but for the life of me I cannot figure it out!

[Link to Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kVSCOiSTNMM1c9QYV9ceN_1j_v4I0bWmNkLgqSBJs2M/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you open your sheet for edits? Share > Anyone with a Link > Can Edit. Its currently locked down.

Comment: @tomf Whoops!  Link is fixed!

Answer (score 1):

B12:

```
=INDEX(SORT(SPLIT(FLATTEN(B2:G10&"×"&A2:A10&"×"&B1:G1), "×"), 1, 0), 1, 2)
```

B13:

```
=INDEX(SORT(SPLIT(FLATTEN(B2:G10&"×"&A2:A10&"×"&B1:G1), "×"), 1, 0), 1, 1)
```

B14:

```
=INDEX(SORT(SPLIT(FLATTEN(B2:G10&"×"&A2:A10&"×"&B1:G1), "×"), 1, 1), 1, 2)
```

B15:

```
=INDEX(SORT(SPLIT(FLATTEN(B2:G10&"×"&A2:A10&"×"&B1:G1), "×"), 1, 1), 1, 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

** edit: use player0's for the overall min and max.

[Check this demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/169olDwaB7n90EQ7YEaq6_4Euqt7JLDBM60c_11HitPs/edit?usp=sharing)

To get the highest or lowest by time slot (put this in I5),

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IFERROR(
   VLOOKUP(
    TRANSPOSE(B1:G1),
    SORT(
     SPLIT(
      FLATTEN(B1:G1&"|"&A2:A&"|"&B2:G),
      "|"),
     3,FALSE),
    {1,2,3},FALSE)))
```

Then to align the lowest per timeslot with that, put this in M5

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(ISBLANK(I5:I),,
   IFERROR(
    VLOOKUP(
     I5:I,
     SORT(
      SPLIT(
       FLATTEN(B1:G1&"|"&A2:A&"|"&B2:G),
       "|"),
      3,FALSE),
     {2,3},FALSE))))
```

If you also wanted conditional formatting for the daily high and low, use a range of B2:G with

```
=AND(LEN(B2),MIN($B2:$G2)=B2)
```

If you really want to have these formulas below the table, change

```
FLATTEN(B1:G1&"|"&A2:A&"|"&B2:G),
```

to

```
FLATTEN(B1:G1&"|"&A2:A10&"|"&B2:G10),
```